# unable to click on the element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

here I am trying to click on the **Login** button I try using xpath, try different xpath unable to click on the login button I am using selenium python on the chrome
I also try the explicit wait using `WebDriverWait` but still not work
here is my python code

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.delete_all_cookies()

url="https://customer.nokia.com/s/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(20)
driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = "//button[@class='btn1 slds-button slds- 
button_outline-brand'][1]").click()
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[@class = 'loginButton slds-button slds- 
button_brand']").click()
```

[image: here the image of website there is mentioned login button]

the output is

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read 
 properties of undefined 
 (reading 'defaultView')
 (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.178)
  Stacktrace:
  Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x00AE37D3]
    (No symbol) [0x00A78B81]
    (No symbol) [0x0097B36D]
    (No symbol) [0x0097E0FB]
    (No symbol) [0x0097DFD0]
    (No symbol) [0x0097E250]
    (No symbol) [0x009B1F68]
    (No symbol) [0x009AFD0B]
    (No symbol) [0x009AE4D8]
    (No symbol) [0x009A3253]
    (No symbol) [0x009CB41C]
    (No symbol) [0x009A2B96]
    (No symbol) [0x009CB774]
    (No symbol) [0x009E1215]
    (No symbol) [0x009CB216]
    (No symbol) [0x009A0D97]
    (No symbol) [0x009A253D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D5ABF2+2510930]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D88EC1+2700065]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D8C86C+2714828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B93480+645344]
    (No symbol) [0x00A80FD2]
    (No symbol) [0x00A86C68]
    (No symbol) [0x00A86D4B]
    (No symbol) [0x00A90D6B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x764300F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77447BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77447B8E+238]
```

if anyone can solve this error would very helpfull to me.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS selector, `a.loginButton`, should work just fine. I would add a `WebDriverWait` to be sure the page is fully loaded before trying to click anything BUT don't use it with implicit waits. Implicit waits are a bad practice according to the Selenium lead and developers. I removed the implicit wait call and added a WebDriverWait. Just use it whenever you need to wait for something. See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Drivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.delete_all_cookies()

url = "https://customer.nokia.com/s/"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.loginButton")).click()
```

Answer (score -1):

`from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[class*="loginButton"]')).click().perform()`

Answer (score -1):

```
You can try with the below XPath 

//div[@class='header container']/child::div[2]/descendant::c-ncp-portal-header/descendant::a[5]

or use the below method.


/*
    The Bhairu Click method works when normal click is not performed 
    it will moved to the action click and final one is javascript click
    */
    public static void BhairuClick(By Locator,String FieldName)
    {
        try {
            WebElement NormalClick=DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(Locator);
            NormalClick.click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            try {
                logger.info("trying with the Action Class Click");
                Actions act=new Actions(getDriver());
                act.moveToElement(getDriver().findElement(Locator)).click().build().perform();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                logger.info("Trying with the Js Click");
                JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();
                js.executeScript("argument[0].click()", getDriver().findElement(Locator));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you gave code in java i need in python